# Spring Boot - Host JaCoCo coverage as static HTML

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I am working with Spring Boot 2.2.5 and Java 8.

I have a Spring Boot webservice that I deploy and run as a linux service using the embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot.

During my Maven build, I generate code coverage metrics using the JaCoCo Maven plugin, and I would like to package and host these static HTML pages when I deploy to my server.

The output for these files is `target/site/jacoco/index.html`.

I know that you can deploy and host webpages through Spring Boot, but I have never accomplished it, and everything I lookup online seems to be more complicated than what im actually trying to do. The only thing i seem to have gathered so far, is that it need to get the html into my /resources directory.

Does anyone know how I can package all of the JaCoCo generated html pages into my .jar file, and host it on my webserver so that I can access it in a similar fashion to how I access any other API in the app?

I build and deploy the app with Jenkins. So if there is some nifty Jenkins way of doing it through my Jenkins.groovy script, that would be nice too.

I would like to be able to access something like: `localhost:8080/my-app-context/coverage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some more digging and the right google questions, the solution was simpler than I thought. I stumbled across [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) article from Baeldung.

The goal:

- get `target/site/jacoco` into the `src/main/resources/static` directory
- get `target/apidocs` into the `src/main/resources/static` directory

The challenge:

- Do it during a Maven/Jenkins build only.

The solution:

- Use a Maven plugin to move the files after successful build

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-javadocs</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/apidocs</outputDirectory>   <!-- output directory -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/target/apidocs</directory>         <!-- source directory -->
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-jacoco</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/jacoco</outputDirectory>   <!-- output directory -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/target/site/jacoco</directory>         <!-- source directory -->
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After putting the above code in my pom.xml, once the app is deployed to my server, both my JaCoCo coverage and my JavaDoc static html pages can be accessed at:

- `<context-root>/apidocs/index.html`
- `<context-root>/jacoco/index.html`

I hope this simplifies it for others looking to do the same.